# Error lnk2026: module unsafe for safeseh image

Tags: visual-c++, unsafe

I got this error when building a sample visual C++ project.
First I downloaded 3 sample projects, all solve the same problem, print out all the prime numbers less than N (you may know these sample projects ?). I built the pure-C project without any problem. But when I tried to build the assembly-based project one, I got this error.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to disable SAFESEH

Comment: Took me a minute to find it in the menus, so here's the path:

Project Properties | Configuration Properties | Linker | Advanced | Image has Safe Exception Handling (last entry in the list)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
Try to disable SAFESEH.
```

From spec: /SAFESEH was specified, but a module was not compatible with the safe exception handling feature.

Comment: I got it, thanks!
But is every assembly-based mudule unsafe ?
And where can I search for the standard of a SAFE module ?

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/ec2b66ec-f1a3-49fb-a8df-329965239284/ HTH

Comment: @LeoChapiro thanks! From there (Mike Danes): 「But it seems that it is easy to make masm generate a safeseh object file, just set the Use Safe Exception Handler MASM property to Yes (see Project Properties, Microsoft Macro Assembler, Advanced). • See also the `.safeseh` MASM directive here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-safeseh?view=msvc-150 but probably you don't need it because your assembly code doesn't really contain any exception handlers.」 (link fixed)

Answer (score 94):

In Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition:

```
Right-click on your project ->
Properties -> 
Configuration Properties ->
Linker ->
Advanced and changed "Image Has Safe Exception Handlers" to "No (/SAFESEH:NO)"
```

Answer (score 47):

A picture is worth 0x3e8 words for the [`/SAFESEH:NO` linker setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a89h429.aspx):

[image]

**Or** you can tell MASM to provide a guarantee that the object contains no exception handlers or that any exception handlers are defined with .SAFESEH, *if you know that to be correct for your assembly code*:

[image]

This will allow you to keep `/SAFESEH` enabled for the project's linking.  But is it correct?  You are making the guarantee! Be sure or use the first option.