# module unsafe for SAFESEH image - VS Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

In compiling a large a program which I have not developed I get the following error when I compile it in Visual Studio Express 2012

error LNK2026: module unsafe for SAFESEH image

I read on other questions that I can turn this error off by going on project properties and under linker options. Unfortunately I can't find those settings in VS Express. Can you anyone provide me with help on how to do it in VS Express either using code or where through the available menus.

Comment: Project + Properties, Linker, Advanced, bottom one named "Image Has Safe Exception Handlers".  Might be hidden in Express, put `/SAFESEH:NO` in the Linker, Command Line, Additional Options box.

Comment: @HansPassant: Express has this option too, it's not hidden.

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710577/error-lnk2026-module-unsafe-for-safeseh-image